# Dependency management with spark

Tags: maven, apache-spark, sbt, dependency-management, ivy

I'm running spark jobs through airflow. Rather than hardcoding a path, or having a directory which is a bucket of jars, I'd like to use a dependency manager to tell me where jars are in a local repo (and even better, maybe get them from a remote repo if not available).

Is there a tool which exists that can do either one or both of these things? I'd be happy with an sbt plugin, apache ivy, or something else completely.

Even better if it's something that sbt can publish to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598612/simplest-ivy-code-to-programmatically-retrieve-dependency-from-maven-central/15603465#15603465

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks, that's perfect.