# Programmatically Downloading Maven Articats (Aether vs.

Tags: ivy, aether

I would like to write a small application which downloads an artifact and its transitive dependencies from an m2-format repository.

There are two obvious choices for this; [Eclipse Aether](http://www.eclipse.org/aether/) or [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)'s API.

Are there any considerations I should make when picking between the two options?

Comment: Actually there may be more choices. If you are using a product for repository storage that has REST API, you can use that API then. Artifactory for example...

Comment: @cantSleepNow Thanks for the suggestion. I really want to avoid tying myself into a specific repository manager, I'd much rather stick to the standard protocol.

Comment: No need to write your own program, ivy has a command-line client, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598612/simplest-ivy-code-to-programmatically-retrieve-dependency-from-maven-central/15603465#15603465