# Programmatically retrieve Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Pls are there any Java libraries that can retrieve Maven dependencies from a POM file? Anything that does not require retrieving out put of a mvn command. Thanks

Comment: Try XML-parsing

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598612/simplest-ivy-code-to-programmatically-retrieve-dependency-from-maven-central ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should parse the `pom.xml` with any xml parser of your choice.

Then construct the link to maven central repository by the following algorithm:
1. Each package in group id is translated to a folder:
Example:

```
<groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId> ==> org/foo/bar
```

2. Artifact name is also a folder and append it to the group id:
   Example:

```
<artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId> ==>  org/foo/bar/some-artifact
```

3. Version also becomes folder:
   Example:

```
<version>1.2.3</version> ==>  org/foo/bar/some-artifact/1.2.3
```

4. Now construct the jar name as "articatId-version.jar" and append it to the link.
5. Prepend the repository and you'll get a full-working path.

Here is a real working example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Gets translated to:

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

As an alternative if you want some library that can work with dependencies don't want to call maven, take a look at [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks.

I used the MavenProject library. Pretty straight forward.
I also used MavenXppReader to get the model that I passed to MavenProject(). The rest was a matter of calling the right methods.